# Edge loop ignores new vertices and selects bigger loops

Tags: edges, topology

I tried to fix my topology on the corner. So I removed triangles and added new point, I wanted to quickly select 4 loops and fill each one, but, it ignores new edges, why is that? It happens very often to me.

Also that point not selected point left side of missing faces is made by subdivide previous edge, is this relevant?

How can I solve that?

[image]

Comment: The loop selection will act as if the vertex doesn't exist, it will select the edge loop along the hole. To select the 4 vertices you're showing, you need to use the lasso for example

Comment: @moonboots what is the reason? its because vertices have missing face?

Comment: Yes that's it, missing faces